# Installing web3: getting different results than the tutorial

Tags: web3js

Mac OS 10.13.6

I installed node and web3
npm install web3
...
+ web3@1.0.0-beta.52
added 331 packages from 246 contributors and audited 9528 packages in 144.776s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Instructions from tutorial:

> var Web3 = require('web3')
>   undefined
>   Web3
>   [Function: Web3]

In the tutorial when the guy types Web3 he gets a long list of items. All I get is : [Function: Web3]
Following the rest of the tutorial, I don't get the results he does.

Comment: Try `var Web3 = require('web3');` and then `var web3 = new Web3('YourProviderAddress');`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes that was the next step in the tutorial and I did that:
> var url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d0d6e36175ea48808cdfb76d8c1397c1'
undefined

> var web3 = new Web3(url)
undefined
> web3
Web3 {
  providerResolver:
   ProviderResolver { providersModuleFactory: ProvidersModuleFactory {} },
  givenProvider: null,
  _currentProvider:
...
> address = '0xE853c56864A2ebe4576a807D26Fdc4A0adA51919'
then I execute: web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => { balance = bal}) 
> balance
ReferenceError: balance is not defined  
when it should return the balance

Comment: Finally got it to work by changing instantiation to:  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d0d6..."))